# C++ Namespaces and Classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, constants

I want to use constants from a class without calling the class, just call the constant, like this:

Header file (.h)

```
class myClass{

   public: 
      const static char CHAR_S = '<';
}
```

Source file (.cpp)

```
using namespace myClass;
char separator = CHAR_S; //I want to call the constant without using the class (myClass::CHAR_S)
```

How can I do this?

Minimal complete example:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    static const char CHAR_S = '<';
};

int main() {
    using namespace MyClass;
    char separator = CHAR_S;
    return 0;
}
```

causes the following compiler errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:21: error: 'MyClass' is not a namespace-name
     using namespace MyClass;
                     ^
main.cpp:7:28: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
     using namespace MyClass;
                            ^
main.cpp:8:22: error: 'CHAR_S' was not declared in this scope
     char separator = CHAR_S;
                      ^
main.cpp:8:10: warning: unused variable 'separator' [-Wunused-variable]
     char separator = CHAR_S;
          ^
```

Comment: It should be `const static char CHAR_S = '<';` not `"<"`

Comment: Yes, mistake just on this question, got it right in my code.

Comment: It also should be `class` not `Class`. CHAR_S should be public.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Note that in C++, `CHAR_S` is a bad name for a constant, because ALL_UPPERCASE almost always indicates macros. You should give it a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class is not a namespace. You cannot refer to the CHAR_S without qualifying it by the class name.

To do what you want, you can simply put the static variable in a namespace:

```
namespace MyClass {
    static const char CHAR_S = '<';
} // namespace MyClass

int main() {
    using namespace MyClass;
    char separator = CHAR_S;
    return 0;
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74fcfee559cc1390

Obviously, calling your namespace `MyClass` is misleading (since it isn't a class), so pick a better name.

Answer (score 3):

myClass is not a namespace, you can't use it like that. I think you want something like this:

```
namespace constants{
    const static char CHAR_S = '<';
};

using constants::CHAR_S;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char a = CHAR_S;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (3.3.7 Class scope)

> 2 The name of a class member **shall only be used as follows**:
>
> — in the scope of its class (as described above) or a class derived
>   (Clause 10) from its class,
>
> — after the . operator applied to an expression of the type of its
>   class (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the -> operator applied to a pointer to an object of its class
>   (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class,
>
> — after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to the name of
>   its class or a class derived from its class.

So I see the only way is to introduce another variable that will refer to the class data member or will have its value. For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    const static char CHAR_S = '<';
};

const char A::CHAR_S;
const char &CHAR_S = A::CHAR_S;

int main()
{
    std::cout << CHAR_S << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple trick; Redefine it with reference. Here's an example.

Header.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER__
#define __HEADER__

class MyClass
{
public:
    const static char CHAR_S = '<';
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
};

#endif
```

Class.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
const static char &CHAR_S = MyClass::CHAR_S;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}
```